# Comparing two lists that are reverse of each other in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures

```
list1 = ["orange", "apple"]
list2 = ["apple", "orange"]
list1 == list2.reverse()
```

The code above returns false and I don't have any cue for this.

Comment: Please remove "I want to" phrase from title. This makes your question look more "stylish"! ;)  Have a look at [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `list.reverse()` returns a `None` and `list1` is obviously not equal to `None`.  `list.reverse()` reverses the list in-place.

You need:

```
list1 == list2[::-1]
```

Or in two steps:

```
list2.reverse()   # list2 is reversed here
list1 == list2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```py
list1 = ["orange", "apple"]
list2 = ["apple", "orange"]
list2.reverse()
list1 == list2
```

As mentioned in other answers, `list.reverse()` method changes list itself and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse list2

```
list1 == list2[::-1]
```